# How to change the source of a content type on SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries, content-type

I have created this content type called Enhanced Folder.
its source it says it is communication site

I then created a site called Home. My problem is that when I go to the document library then to library settings and Add from existing site content types. I dont see me content type Enhanced Folder.

Answer (score -1):

Did you create the content type in the Same Site as a Site level content type or did you create it in a different library? If you are wanting to share content types around your environment you would want to use the Content Type Hub. You can then create your very general content types in one location and each other site will be able to subscribe to the Content Type Hub to get the content types and associated Site Columns from there.